# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token !=

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have the following `Form` on which I am performing `Validation`. I have the following code:

```
<form method="post" asp-action="actionName" asp-controller="controllerName" id="myForm">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>    
    <div class="card">
        ...
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 m-t-20">
                <div class="fg-line">
                    <label asp-for="Name" class="fg-label" for="name">Name</label>
                        <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" required />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 m-t-20">
                <div class="fg-line">
                    <label asp-for="Age" class="fg-label" for="age">Age</label>
                        <input asp-for="Age" class="form-control" id="age" name="age" required />
                        <span asp-validation-for="age" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        ...
    </div>
</form>

<script src="~/js/app.js"></script>

@section Scripts{
    @{ await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial"); }

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $('form').validate({
            onfocusout: function (element) {
                this.element(element);
            },
            messages: {
                amount: 'Enter Name',
                age: 'Enter Age',
            },
            highlight: function (element) {
                $(element).closest('.input-group').addClass('has-error');
            },
            unhighlight: function (element) {
                $(element).closest('.input-group').removeClass('has-error');
                $(element).closest('.input-group').addClass('has-success');
            }
        })


        $(document).ready(function(){
            if(@ViewBag.userId != null){
                var userId = @ViewBag.userId;

        }


    </script>
}
```

When I try to submit the form empty (without entering any data), I expect the warning messages to pop-up. However, I am not seeing any message next to the field. But, I can see that the form is not getting submitted and the cursor is prompting me to enter some text. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What is `@ViewBag.userId` outputting?

Comment: @LucaKiebel It is outputting the `userId` from `Controller`. I got `12`.

Comment: So. It's always going to be a number or null?

Comment: Yes. I am looking for a number here. The only other case is that the `ViewBag` comes empty.

Comment: Can you post the code of the document ready function that actually get's executed, meaning after asp is done with the preprocessing?

Comment: There seems to be an issue with what actually gets executed on the client

Comment: Can we take this conversation to chat? We can post the solution here as an answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179487/discussion-between-luca-kiebel-and-dashamlav).

Comment: You are using mvc's client side validation using `jquery.validate.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js.` Delete all your scripts - you do not use the `.validate()` function - that is already all done and configured by the plugins. And remove the `required` attributes (they are ignored) and add `[Required]` attributes to your properties. Ad its not even clear what your `var userId = @ViewBag.userId;` is for since you never use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the razor code is not being evaluated at the same time as your JavaScript code. You have to check first for the null value using razor and then use JS code

```
 @if(ViewBag.userId != null)
  {
       //your code    
  }
```